# Qt5 throws std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qcustomplot

I'm trying to use QCustomPlot in my console application. I started by creating a simple wrapper for it that's suitable for my uses. The wrapper was supposed to However, I get std::bad_alloc errors every time I try to show the window.

This is my code, I've created a wrapper class in `Plot.hpp`:

```
class Plot
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        QApplication* app;
        QMainWindow* window;
        QCustomPlot* plotWidget;
    public:
        Plot(std::string& name);
        // OTHER METHODS
        void showPlot();
};
```

and in my `Plot.cpp` file I have the following:

```
Plot::Plot(std::string& name) : name(name)
{
    char *gui_argv[] = {(char*)(name.c_str()), NULL};
    int gui_argc = sizeof(gui_argv) / sizeof(char*) - 1;
    app = new QApplication(gui_argc, gui_argv);
    window = new QMainWindow();
    // Add plot Widget
    plotWidget = new QCustomPlot(window);
    window->setCentralWidget(plotWidget);
    plotWidget->plotLayout()->clear();
}

// OTHER METHODS

void Plot::showPlot()
{
    // Run the GUI
    window->show();
    app->exec();
}
```

and I have the following in my `main.cpp`:

```
int main()
{
    std::string title = "Testing";
    Util::Plot *plotWindow = new Util::Plot(title);
    // NO OTHER STATEMENTS
    plotWindow->showPlot();
    return 0;
}
```

Through GDB I got this stack trace but I couldn't really decipher it to find what the error is. It goes deep into the internals of QT:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7279e97 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff727b801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff78d08fb in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff78d6d3a in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff78d6d95 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff78d6fe8 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff529e402 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff530a22a in QListData::detach(int) () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff534475e in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff549a48f in QCoreApplication::arguments() () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007fffef9e3791 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#11 0x00007fffef9e3c8d in QXcbIntegration::wmClass() const () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#12 0x00007fffef9f8e03 in QXcbWindow::create() () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#13 0x00007fffef9e4bfb in QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#14 0x00007ffff5a6229e in QWindowPrivate::create(bool, unsigned long long) () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#15 0x00007ffff6245add in QWidgetPrivate::create_sys(unsigned long long, bool, bool) () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#16 0x00007ffff624619d in QWidget::create(unsigned long long, bool, bool) () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#17 0x00007ffff6252a96 in QWidget::setVisible(bool) () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
# The following is line window->show()
#18 0x00007ffff7bd3179 in Util::Plot::showPlot() (this=0x55555576fd80) at ./lib/util/Plot.cpp:71
#19 0x00005555555549b3 in main() () at ./lib/test/PlotTest.cpp:16
```

I've also verified that the pointers to `window`, `app`, and `plotWidget` are not null. So basically, just creating the `QMainWindow` and trying to show it without even doing any other actions causes this failure to occur.  What could be wrong here? What am I missing?

**Extra:**
I don't think the following is the cause of the issue. But just in case:
I'm not using QT Studio, I have written my own makefile that builds `libQCustomPlot.so` and my own app and links them against the necessary QT libraries. No failures or warnings through compilation.

**Edit1:**
I forgot to post the original error! It's just the following with no additional info/clarification:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QApplication takes `argc` by reference and expects this reference to be valid for the lifetime of the application. Once your Plot function ends, QApplication is left with a dangling reference to `gui_argc` so when the call to QApplication::arguments (as seen in your back trace) is made, undefined behavior occurs. You can fix this by making `argc` persistent somewhere.

Comment: Yep, [for reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication): _Warning: The data referred to by `argc` and `argv` must stay valid for the entire lifetime of the `QApplication` object._

Comment: The problem occurred in my code appearing as if a race condition.  Innocuous code changes would appear to fix it for a time.  Thanks for the solution!